# How to calculate the memory size of a page table for a single process?

Tags: memory, operating-system, computer-science, paging, virtual-memory

In a given system with a 32-bit address space and 4KB page size, the main memory is 16MB. The page table is a single-level page table that is always allocated in the main memory. Each entry in the page table contains a frame number and 4 control bits.

What is the required memory size in megabytes (MB) to store the page table for a single process?

I have tried several calculations by playing with the given sizes and bit numbers. But none of them was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The physical address space is 16MiB. 16MiB / 4KiB = 4096 = 2^12 pages in physical memory. This means that we need 12 bits to index a physical page. We also have 4 control bits, so in total we need 16 bits = 2 bytes per entry in the page table.

The virtual address space is 32-bit = 4GiB. 4GiB / 4KiB = 1048576 pages in virtual memory. This means that our single-level page table must have this many entries. Each entry has 2 bytes, so the table will have 2097152 bytes = 2MiB in total.

Answer (score 0):

One way to calculate the size of the page table is to split a virtual address into a "page table index + offset" format; use "page table index" to determine how many page table entries there needs to be, and then multiply that by the size of one page table entry.

"4 KiB pages" would imply that 12 bits are used for the offset within a page (because `1 << 12 = 4096 = 4 KiB`). If we assume (see note) that virtual addresses are 32 bits, then the size of a page table index must be `32 - 12 = 20 bits` and a page table must have `1 << 20 = 1048576 entries`.

If we assume (see note) that physical addresses are also 32 bits, then the size of a page table entry must be at least `32 - 12 = 20 bits` too. However, there's always some more bits in a page table entry that are used for other purposes (to say if the page is/isn't present, possibly to determine whether the page is writable or executable, possibly flags saying if the page has been accessed or modified, etc); and it'd be awkward for a page table entry not to be a convenient "power of 2" number of whole bytes (or words?). Because of this I'd expect that the size of a page table entry would be rounded up to 32 bits (4 bytes per entry), or maybe 64 bits (8 bytes per entry) even if unused padding is added to achieve that; but it's impossible to tell from the (lack of) information in the question how many other bits there are in a page table entry.

All of this combined means that the size of the whole page table is most likely `1048576 entries * 4 bytes per entry = 4194304 bytes = 4 MiB`, but it's impossible to be sure because the question lacks information.

Note: The words "In a given system with a 32-bit address space" has 2 problems. The first problem is that you can't tell if it's talking about the physical address space or the virtual address space (and these can be, and often are, different sizes). The other problem is that (if you take it literally) 32 bits is extremely tiny. This causes you to rely on assumptions - e.g. maybe the physical address space and the virtual address space are the same size, and maybe a physical address and a virtual address are 32 bits, and therefore the address space is 4 GiB (or 1099511627776 bits and not 32 bits), but maybe those assumptions are wrong.

Comment: Actually that's what I got at first and this is very convincing but the right answer is 2MB

Comment: @MohammadYusuf: There's no way to adjust the numbers (e.g. halve the virtual address space size, or halve the size of a page table entry) in a way that causes "2 MiB" to be even slightly plausible. Significantly more likely is that your lecturer is an idiot (barely aware of the content they're teaching, sloppy/error prone at modifying last year's assignment to make it different this year, and telling students a wrong answer is "right").

Comment: You seem to be too focused on real-world cases when the question is clearly academic. You wrongly assumed that a page table entry is 4 bytes. However this question is indeed very vague. By 32-bit address space, the OP must have meant virtual address space. If the physical address space was 4GiB, the information of a 16MiB physical memory would be entirely useless (and in academic questions like these there's usually no useless piece of info), as the amount of RAM installed doesn't change page table size.

Comment: @DarkAtom: The idea that a university can sell people "misinformation based on fantasy" and not be considered wrong because "it's academia so people shouldn't expect real/useful information" is horrifying.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has no correct answer. First, in a virtual memory system, the address space will have to be divided into a system space and a user space. Thus, you will need at least two page tables. The logical address range for each space will be defined by the system.

Second, in a virtual memory system, a page table does not need to provide access to the entire logical address space. The operating system configuration could limit your address space to one page so the entire table could take up only a few bytes.

I'd be curious to know who came up with such and idiotic computer science problem.